# How to sort ids like A1, A2, A10 in pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark

How do I sort ids like `A1, A2, A10, B1` etc in pyspark?

I would like to be able to sort the following code (the actual list is longer with other letters etc) A-Z. If I add, say, `A13` - new code and then A-Z, I get `A1,A10,A11`, etc

When I try sorting with `orderBy`, I am getting data like:

```
A1
A10
A11
A2
A21
etc..
```

Answer (score 3):

You will have to split up your column temporarily to achieve what you want. The following code:

```
from pyspark.sql import types as T

vals = ['A1','F1' ,'A10','A11','C23','A2','A21']
tempNames = ['letter', 'number']

df = spark.createDataFrame(vals, T.StringType())
df = df.select(F.regexp_extract('value', "(\w)", 1).alias(tempNames[0])
              ,F.regexp_extract('value', "\w(\d*)", 1).cast('int').alias(tempNames[1])
              ,df.value).orderBy(tempNames).drop(*tempNames)

df.show()
```

creates temporarily two columns ('letter' and 'number') from your column...

```
+------+------+-----+ 
|letter|number|value| 
+------+------+-----+ 
|     A|     1|   A1| 
|     F|     1|   F1| 
|     A|    10|  A10| 
|     A|    11|  A11| 
|     C|    23|  C23| 
|     A|     2|   A2| 
|     A|    21|  A21| 
+------+------+-----+
```

...and uses them to sort your column:

```
+-----+ 
|value| 
+-----+ 
|   A1| 
|   A2| 
|  A10| 
|  A11|
|  A21|
|  C23|
|   F1|
+-----+
```

An even shorter solution stated by @pault:

```
df.orderBy(F.regexp_extract(F.col("value"), r"[A-Za-z]+", 0), F.regexp_extract(F.col("value"), r"\d+", 0).cast('int')).show()
```

Comment: You could avoid the `select` and `drop` and just do the `orderBy`: `df.orderBy(F.regexp_extract(F.col("id"), r"[A-Za-z]+", 0), F.regexp_extract(F.col("id"), r"\d+", 0).cast('int')).show()`